# php-How to turn a negative number string into a int

Tags: php

I'm trying to compute a number that is pulled in as string but its a negative number. I want to turn the string that is a negative number into a negative int. Whenever i try a code like below it shows its negative. But the value i got is in an array and is a string and when i try the same thing it says its not negative. How do you convert a string(-50.00) thats in an array to a int that i can compute

```
<?php
$num= "-50.00" ;
if($num<0){
echo " number is negative";
}else{
  echo "number is not negative";
}
?>
```

Comment: var_dump((int) "-50.00");

Comment: php is smart enough to do type conversion itself:- https://3v4l.org/Xu6jO

Comment: @AlivetoDie In theory, but it has a nasty habit of type-juggling to something you didn't expect.  You're better off making it explicit with a type cast

Comment: @GordonM  agreed :)

Comment: Thank you for all the recommendations but whats with all the down votes

Answer (score 3):

use type conversion:-

```
$num = (int)$num;
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/bqQZH

Note:- if you want to convert all string values of an array to int then use [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) along with [inval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
<?php
$num= array("-50.00","-80.00") ;
$integerIDs = array_map('intval', $num);
print_r($integerIDs);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/BluaW

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can use `(int)$num`